# why do we have a pointer to a constant in the syntax of scanf and printf functions?

Tags: c

The syntax of scanf function is
 int scanf(const char *format, ...);
and the syntax of printf function is also 
int printf(const char *format, ...);

why do we have a pointer to a constant here , and why do we have variable arguments specified here ,what's the use of it ?

Comment: Because the format you pass to these function is directly a value. So the underlying type is a constant string (char*). It never changes during program execution.

Comment: C does not have symbolic constants (except for enum-constants). `const` qualified objects are still variables.

Comment: "why do we have variable arguments specified here ,what's the use of it ?"  It is there, because the printf family of functions is obscure, mildly put. These functions are allowed to exist by tradition, even though they are notoriously dangerous because of the non-existent type safety. I would be interested to know how many billions of dollars that the printf-like functions have cost mankind. When writing programs of your own, you should avoid variable argument lists like the plague.

Comment: @Lundin Interesting comment about `printf()` weaknesses.  May I offer an  [output alternative](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115143/formatted-print-without-the-need-to-specify-type-matching-specifiers-using-gene)?

Answer (score 2):

`const` in the format specifier provides a guarantee that library woould never change the contents pointed by the format string.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer to `format` is an input data to the functions which is not supposed to be changed. Therefore it is const. Further, depending on functions the parameters either input or output, and either const or not by their nature. However due to the functions are variadic they are not specified and respectively have no const or non-const specifiers. The printf is an out-function, therefore it expects the rest of parameters are in-parameters as well as `format`, and thus const. The scanf - is an in-function, therefore it writes to the rest parameters following by `format`, and thus those must be writable.